# JavaScript Random Positive or Negative Number

Tags: javascript, random

I need to create a random -1 or 1 to multiply an already existing number by. Issue is my current random function generates a -1, 0, or 1. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Don't use your existing function - just call `Math.random()`.  If < 0.5 then -1, else 1:

```
var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
```

The `Math.random()` method returns a floating-point number that's greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1.

Comment: Works perfectly, funny I couldn't find an answer anywhere online.

Answer (score 88):

I've always been a fan of

```
Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1
```

as it just sort of makes sense.

- `Math.round(Math.random())` will give you 0 or 1
- Multiplying the result by 2 will give you 0 or 2
- And then subtracting 1 gives you -1 or 1.

Intuitive!

Comment: In my opinion this is a better "random" - or + creator. The selected answer just doesn't work for me because what if i want a number that is less than 4 that isn't negative? This is just an all around better solution.

Comment: @Brendan - While that I agree that this is a more flexible solution, the OP's requirement was specifically for needing to return a "random -1 or +1".  For what it's worth, this solution, while more flexible - also requires more operations - in terms of an extra call to `Math.round`, multiplication, and subtraction - vs. a single conditional check.

Answer (score 21):

why dont you try:

```
(Math.random() - 0.5) * 2
```

50% chance of having a negative value with the added benefit of still having a random number generated.

Or if really need a -1/1:

```
Math.ceil((Math.random() - 0.5) * 2) < 1 ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: `(Math.random() - 0.5) * 2` is the cleanest way I've seen

Comment: I think this does not give a perfectly equal +/- random number, or am I wrong ? `0.999... - 0.5 = 0.4999...`, but `0 - 0.5 = -0.5`. (as Math.random() returns 0 to 0.999...)

Answer (score 11):

Just for the fun of it:

```
var plusOrMinus = [-1,1][Math.random()*2|0];
```

or

```
var plusOrMinus = Math.random()*2|0 || -1;
```

But use what you think will be maintainable.

Comment: On one hand, I should say there's something to be said for readability.  On the other hand, kudos for shaving 3 characters off of my answer (though I could argue that all 3 characters are unnecessary whitespace).  Mine is 1 character shorter if you also eliminate the `0` from `0.5`.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

There are really lots of ways to do it as previous answers show.

The fastest being combination of Math.round() and Math.random:

```
// random_sign = -1 + 2 x (0 or 1); 
random_sign = -1 + Math.round(Math.random()) * 2;
```

You can also use Math.cos() ([which is also fast](http://jsperf.com/plus-one-or-minus-one/2)):

```
// cos(0) = 1
// cos(PI) = -1
// random_sign = cos( PI x ( 0 or 1 ) );
random_sign = Math.cos( Math.PI * Math.round( Math.random() ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

After ages, just let me state the obvious;

```
Math.sign(Math.random()-0.5);
```

Comment: since this has a (tiny) chance to return a zero, I don't think it's quite what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [underscore.js shuffle](https://Underscorejs.org/#shuffle)

```
var plusOrMinus = _.shuffle([-1, 1])[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random() - Math.random()`
Or
`Math.random() * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1 )`
Here you go