# How to get random 1 or -1 in canvas (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, random

How can I get random -1 or 1 (not between -1 or 1, just -1 or 1, only this 2 values) in canvas?

I know that to get random number I can use:

```
Math.random()
```

But I want only random 1 or -1.

Answer (score 4):

```
var plusOrMinus = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
```

(please use the search first [JavaScript Random Positive or Negative Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611830/javascript-random-positive-or-negative-number))

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var n = (Math.random()>=0.50)?1:-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in a case someone doesn't get how the ternar operator works, ill write the same in the other way:

```
var value;
if(Math.random() > 0.5) value = 1;
else value = -1;
```

ups, fixed coma. thx.

Comment: Wrong: `0,5` -> `0.5`

Answer (score -1):

Solution that does not use branching :

```
((Math.random()+0.5)<<1)-1
```

This solution uses a formula that matches the [0, 1] interval into the {-1, 1} set.
Here i used `floor` to do so.

Let's see how : 
If i add 0.5 to `Math.random()` i'm now in [0.5, 1.5].
After flooring the result is in the {0, 1} set.
Now you multiply by two => { 0, 2} set.
Now remove 1 => {-1, 1} set.

So the formula is this one :

```
2*Math.floor(Math.random()+0.5)-1
```

Faster (but more cryptic :-) ) using the shift operator :

```
((Math.random()+0.5)<<1)-1
```

Unfortunately... branching is faster as you can see here (look in the console).

https://jsfiddle.net/h6d8bthd/